# accessing jquery mobile elements by role

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, mustache

I'm 90% sure I'm doing this 100% wrong:

I'm building a Phonegap + jQuery Mobile app, and am trying to build as much code re-use as I can into the app.  I have a single html file, with multiple

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_name">
```

elements for page page of the app. Each page element has typical:

```
<div id="header" data-role="header">
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
<p>Page Info</p>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

And finally:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="footnav" data-position="fixed">
   <div data-role="navbar">
       <ul><li></li></ul>
   </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Now, in the spirit of reuse, I want to fill the data-role="navbar" divs with the same thing, so I threw together a mustache template like:

```
function doNavigationMenu() {
  var navdata = {
     navlist: [
        { href : "ixinfo", text: "Ix" },
        { href : "ptinfo", text: "Px" },
        { href : "dxinfo", text: "Dx" },
        { href : "rxinfo", text: "Rx" },
        { href : "txinfo", text: "Tx" }
     ]
  };

  var template = "{{#navlist}}<li><a href='#{{href}}'>{{text}}</a></li>{{/navlist}}";
  var content = $.mustache(template, navdata);
  console.log(content); 
  $(".navbar ul").html( content ); **//<<< this doesn't work**
  $(".footnav").trigger( 'create' ); **//<<<This doesn't work**
}
```

This function is called by the phonegap `onDeviceReady` event, ensuring the app is ready for me to muck with html.  But since I'm modifying content after the CSS classes are applied by jQuery mobile, and since this is a single page (to avoid having to build a HUGE state machine), the jQuery Mobile styles are missing on the first "page". I initially gave all `navbar` divs the same ID, but that's just dumb, but the only other thing I have to select by is `data-role="navbar"`, and I don't now how. I've read that I need to fire the `.trigger('create')` on all my navbars,  but I'm stumped on how to.

In summary: I want to use a single html file with multiple pages, but use mustache templating to allow easier maintenance and size of code in my mobile app, and don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on my fiddle,

```
http://jsfiddle.net/idangozlan/27QMM/1/
```

You didnt use the correct selector which should be `$('[data-role="navbar"]')`..

Comment: That works, but on every page except the first page.  on divs 2-5, the navbar looks perfect.  On page 1, it's an unstyled list. See this gist: https://gist.github.com/nikmartin/b46a05b5052e0424aad1

Comment: I'm giving you the answer, because your method is a cleaner way to access the roles.  The problem is not related to roles, so I'm asking it again. Thanks!